# Interpreting Java's Post-Crash Call Stack

Tags: stack, call

I am new to Java and am having troubles interpreting the call stack below (from Crashlytics). I got some questions:

1. Can anybody tell me which method exactly raised `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException()` the exception?
2. To my confusion, both `com.a.data.SystemParameters.getA()` and `com.a.data.SystemParameters.getC()` are simple one-line getter methods, they return corresponding dictionaries. How can an exception "occur" there?
3. I never call `getA()` inside `getC()` nor vice versa. How can that be? What kind of call stack is this? It's not really a "stack", is it?

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>       at com.a.data.SystemParameters.getA()
>       at com.a.data.SystemParameters.getC()
>       at com.a.data.SystemParameters.isOutOfDate()
>       at com.a.ui.activities.LoginActivity$SaveSystemParametersTask.doInBackground()
>       at com.a.ui.activities.LoginActivity$SaveSystemParametersTask.doInBackground()
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: Post the code for `SystemParameters.getA`. Are you saying `getC` does not call `getA`? The stack trace does not lie usually...

Comment: public ArrayList<Airline> getA() {
        return mVisualA;
    }

Comment: public ArrayList<Country> getC() {
        return mVisualC;
    }

Comment: That does not match up with the stacktrace. Are you sure you are looking at the source for the code that did actually get deployed?

Comment: Yes, 100%. The call stack also specifically says both methods are from "SystemParameters", and I am also looking at that exact file. BTW, I used ProGuard code obfuscation.

Comment: There is one more getA() in my project, but it's not in SystemParameters.java, it's in InternalStorage.java. However, Android Studio says that method is never even used (its name is grayed out). Here is its implementation anyways: public ArrayList<Airline> getA() {
        return restore(AIRLINES_FILE_NAME);   }